# Refactoring existing class logic

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, hashmap

My upload format is incorrect and the structure of the database cannot be changed as my partner is pulling the data correctly on the iOS side.

how the database should look
[image: how the database should look]

[how it actually looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q44dQ.png)

As you can see, its a level deeper than is needed. I'm really not sure what's needed in order to remove the questionHash field without iterating over on each upload.

My Quiz class;

```
public class Quiz {

HashMap<String, Question> questions;
ArrayList<Score> previousScores;
String topicName;
String description;
String displayImage, title, quizUpvotes, averageTime, quizUID, creatorUID, quizDownvotes;


public Quiz(HashMap<String, String> questions, String topicName, String description, String displayImage, String title, String quizUpvotes, String quizAverageTime, String quizUID) {
    this.topicName = topicName;
    this.questions = new HashMap<String, Question>();
    this.previousScores = new ArrayList<Score>();
    this.description = description;
    this.displayImage = displayImage;
    this.title = title;
    this.quizUpvotes = quizUpvotes;
    this.averageTime = quizAverageTime;
    this.quizUID = quizUID;

    HashMap<String, Question> questionHashMap = new HashMap<String, Question>();
}
```

constructors ect...

```
public class Question {

HashMap<String, String> questionHash;


public Question() {
    this.questionHash = new HashMap<String, String>();
}

public HashMap<String, String> getQuestionHash() {
    return questionHash;
}

public void setQuestionHash(HashMap<String, String> questionHash) {
    this.questionHash = questionHash;
}
```

Its being uploaded as a single object:

```
quizAreaReference.child(uuidAsString).child("main").setValue(quizToBeUploaded).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
```

My quiz is displaying and pulling logic as it is, so im reluctant to refactor too much, but im looking for a way to remove the "questionHash" node in the database.

Comment: please show us more code of java and need to check ```uuidAsString```

Comment: I'm not sure what Json library is being used here but if it's Jackson you could use `@JsonAnyGetter` etc. to treat the nested map elements as part of the `Question` json object. Have a look here for more info: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations

Comment: @Thomas Many thanks I'll check it out.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: What does the HashMap in the Question class do ?
Seems like a thing you coudl/should get rid of.
Question class should look like: 

class Question {
    String Question;
    String AnswerA;
    String AnswerB;
    String AnswerC;
    String AnswerD;
}